# Type hinting when numpy functions return pandas Series or DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, type-hinting

When using Python type hinting, how do I handle numpy functions that return pandas objects when applied to such?

For example, when I write

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def clip_probability(probability: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return np.clip(
        probability,
        0,
        1,
    )
```

I get `Expected type 'Series', got 'ndarray' instead` *even though `np.clip` does return a Series when the first argument is one*.

In case there is an IDE specific solution, I'm using PyCharm 2020.

Comment: In this specific case, `np.clip` could be replaced with [`pd.Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html), IIUC.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried casting the return of the function? Numpy and Pandas are good at casting between their types usually. Like so:

```
return pd.Series(np.clip(
        probability,
        0,
        1,
    )
)
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution without code changes (while this is a functional no-op it still means additional function calls). Note that the output of `np.clip` is *already* a `pd.Series`

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast):

```py
from typing import cast

def clip_probability(probability: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    out = np.clip(
        probability,
        0,
        1,
    )
    return cast(pd.Series, out)
```

This does nothing during runtime, but signals to the type checker that `out` is indeed a Pandas series.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does this literally do nothing at runtime, with support on the interpreter level, or does it still translate to a handful of byte code instructions?

Comment: (I unaccepted the answer for now, just in case someone comes along and shows a clean way to monkey patch type hints. That way I wouldn't have to do this cast every time I call `np.clip`/`np.exp` etc. but only once for each.)

Comment: This is one additional function call that returns immediately: https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/src/typing.py#L1436-L1444. I don't think you can make your Pandas Series small enough for this to matter.

Comment: I agree with that, I was just curious. Anyway, the extra source code each time I call such functions still bothers me slightly. If no one has anything more succinct, I'll re-accept

Answer (score -1):

`np.clip` returns an `ndarray` (see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html).

You first need to convert this *ndarray* to a *Pandas Series*:

```
return pd.Series(np.clip(
        probability,
        0,
        1,
    ))
```

Comment: `import numpy as np;
import pandas as pd;
type(np.clip(pd.Series([0,2]), 0, 1))`